# how to destroy session in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net

I'm using session in my asp.net project in a jquery function. My problem is that I want to use the content of the session once.when I refresh the page I don't want that the content of the session will be used an other time.I tried to use @Session.Abandon() but it didn't work. How can I destroy a session after use?

this is a part of my code : (the jquery function)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
     setTimeout(function () {
        ui.notify('Notification', 'operation completed successfully')
    .effect('slide');          
    }, @Session["succes"]);        

});
```

Any help please

Comment: TempData only lasts until it is called, so maybe that is something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Set it equal to `null`. This will clear it out.

As stated in the comments, `TempData` or `ViewData` may be a better choice in this situation.

Comment: the problem that in my example the notification will be shown even @Session["succes"]) is null

Comment: See my update, or consider changing your logic to see if the session is equal to something.